# Truffle send transaction callback causes "Buffer is not defined" error

Tags: web3js, truffle

Using Truffle to send a transaction to a local TestRPC causes a `Buffer is not defined` error. The transaction is successfully executed, but the callback causes an error.

Here is my code:

```
import { View, Text, Button } from 'react-native';
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import styles from './styles';
import { default as Web3} from 'web3';
import { default as contract } from 'truffle-contract'
import metacoin_artifacts from '../../contracts/MetaCoin.json'

const web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("http://localhost:8545"));

var MetaCoin = contract(metacoin_artifacts);

MetaCoin.setProvider(web3.currentProvider);

var amount = 10;
var account = '0x8d8a8258daea0fab0309b378b915b2eb7862d5bc';
var receiver = '0x6e6d32a7c1b8c288f2f707c3c2910cb383f3cd83';
var meta;

const sendCoins = () => {
  MetaCoin.deployed().then(function(instance) {
    meta = instance;
    // console.dir(meta);
    return meta.sendCoin(receiver, amount, {from: account});
  }).then(function() {
    console.log('Transaction complete!');
  }).catch(function(e) {
    console.log(e);
  });
};

class Ethereum extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Button
          onPress={sendCoins}
          title="Send coins"
          color="#841584"
          accessibilityLabel="Learn more about this purple button"
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

export default Ethereum;
```

My setup is as follows:

Using Truffle I've compiled and deployed the MetaCoin contracts to a local EthereumJS TestRPC.

I've manually copied the compiled contract files `MetaCoin.json`, `ConvertLib.json` and `Migrations.json` into a React-Native app.

I'm importing both `web3` and `truffle-contract` into a React-Native component.

A screenshot of the full error trace is below:

[image]